Multi Entry Schengen Visa - can do multiple individual short trips to different countries?
With a Swiss-issued multi entry Schengen visa, can one go for multiple, individual, weekend trips to other countries? (Of course as long as one is within the correct dates, and the days limit)
Or does every trip require some proof of intention of visiting Switzerland. I’m an EU citizen travelling with non EU wife (we don’t live in EU).
Ideally we’d like to use the fact that she got that Visa (Visite familiale / amicale) and go for a weekend to Paris, Amsterdam, Rome, each on separate weekends

Does this answer your question? Does a multiple-entry Schengen visa allow visiting other Schengen countries later, without going via the issuing country?

Note that while this is in the linked question above, the answers don’t make it clear: your first trip must include the country which issued the visa as its main destination (largest number of days) and should as much as possible follow the itinerary given in the application. After that you can do as you wish (following the rules on validity, duration, 90/180, having a valid reason, having enough money, etc.)

@jcaron except that under the free movement directive it's not really feasible to impose any kind of negative consequences on someone whose first trip isn't to the country that issued the visa.


I’m an EU citizen travelling with non EU wife (we don’t live in EU).

In this case it really doesn't matter.  Your wife, when she is traveling with you, is a "person enjoying the right of free movement under union law" and therefore cannot be refused entry except "on  grounds of public policy, public security or public health."
In case your wife ever wants to use the visa for a trip without you, it's fine, as long as the first trip reflects the itinerary submitted with the visa application.

What do you mean by "it doesn't matter"? She can just be with me with no documents, and a local, non-EU marriage certificate and travel freely with me? This sounds like a security risk, what if the certificate is fake?

@LSK she needs a passport (and, depending on her nationality, possibly a visa to enter).  She also needs to establish that she is your wife; for short-term travel, authorities are unlikely to question the validity of the marriage -- my parents never showed a marriage certificate, let alone being required to have an authenticated one, but they had the same surname in their passports.  My wife and I don't, but she has a Croatian passport and we married only a few years before Croatia joined.  So yes, I suppose it's a security risk, but one that many countries' authorities seem willing to take.

But what I really mean is, as I alluded in a comment above, that even if she uses the Swiss visa on the first trip to travel somewhere else, as long as she is with you there should be no questions about your destination or purpose of travel, much less anything relating to the main destination rule, so no investigation that might lead to the visa's revocation, and there is no basis for refusing entry as a consequence of any perceived irregularity in the visa application.  And even if they did somehow revoke the visa, they would still have to let her in.
